# Terrific performance difference between almost equal methods

Tags: performance, optimization, compiler-construction, f#

while working on a project I accidentally noticed that the same method with only one additional (unused) argument manages to run even ten times faster than the other one, with optimizations enabled.

```
type Stream () =
    static member private write (x, o, a : byte[]) = (for i = 0 to 3 do a.[o + i] <- byte((x >>> 24 - i * 8) % 256)); 4
    static member private format f x l = Array.zeroCreate l |> fun a -> (f(x, 0, a) |> ignore; a)
    static member private format1 f x l o = Array.zeroCreate l |> fun a -> (f(x, 0, a) |> ignore; a)
    static member Format (value : int) =  Stream.format (fun (x: int, i, a) -> Stream.write(x, i, a)) value 4
    static member Format1 (value : int) =  Stream.format1 (fun (x: int, i, a) -> Stream.write(x, i, a)) value 4
```

When tested, `Stream.Format1` runs much faster than `Stream.Format`, although the only difference between the private members `Stream.format` and `Stream.format1` is just the `o` argument, which moreover is unused by the method itself.

How does the compiler treat in so different ways two almost identical methods?

**EDIT: thanks for the explanation and sorry for the ignorance.**

Comment: How many iterations did you run to get the timings? One? A million? You need to make your sample broad enough to smooth out cache effects,  kernel scheduling, and the like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that when you call `Format1` with just a single argument, it only returns a function. It doesn't do the actual formatting yet. This means that if you compare the performance of:

```
Stream.Format 42
Stream.Format1 42
```

... then you're actually comparing the performance of actual formatting (that creates the array and writes something in it) in the first case and the performance of code that simply returns a function value without doing anything.

If you're not using the `o` parameter of `format1` for anything, then you can just pass in some dummy value, to actually evaluate the function and get the result. Then you should get similar performance:

```
Stream.Format 42
Stream.Format1 42 ()
```

Answer (score 4):

`Format` actually invokes `Array.zeroCreate l |> fun a -> (f(x, 0, a) |> ignore; a)`.

`Format1` returns a function that when passed an object invokes `Array.zeroCreate l |> fun a -> (f(x, 0, a) |> ignore; a)`.

I.e., one does actual work, the other is merely a partial function application; the latter is obviously quicker.

If you're not familiar with partial function application, there is a section in the F# docs titled 'Partial Application of Arguments' that's worth reading over: [Functions (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233229.aspx)